# Return NULL from XML EXPLICIT subquery where no rows exist

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This is probably simple to do, but I'm having a brain-fart on this one...

I'm using `FOR XML EXPLICIT` as part of a subquery so that I can explicitly define the format of the returned XML.  Therefore I'm using `UNION ALL` to define that format.

This is working fine, but I need it to return `NULL` if there are no rows in that sub-query... at the moment it is returning an empty root element: `<codes/>`.  That is because I need the first row for the definition.

[Here is a sqlfiddlecom with everything below for you to look at.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62f06/1)

This is a version of the TSQL as it currently is...

```
SELECT
    P.[PROJECTID],
    P.[PROJECTNAME],
    (   SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    1 AS TAG,
                    NULL AS PARENT,
                    NULL AS 'codes!1',
                    NULL AS 'code!2!!element',
                    NULL AS 'code!2!split'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    2 AS TAG,
                    1 AS PARENT,
                    NULL,                   
                    C.[CODE],
                    C.[SPLIT]
                FROM [CODES] C
                WHERE C.[PROJECTID] = P.[PROJECTID]
             ) AS [CODEXMLDATA]
        FOR XML EXPLICIT
    ) AS [CODESXML]
FROM [PROJECTS] P
```

Example data would be along the lines of

```
PROJECTS table
PROJECTID PROJECTNAME
1         This
2         That
3         Other

CODES table
PROJECTID CODE SPLIT
1         ABC  45
1         BCD  65
2         CDE  100
```

The result is coming out as...

```
PROJECTID PROJECTNAME CODESXML
1         This        <codes><code split="45">ABC</code><code split="55">BCD</code></codes>
2         That        <codes><code split="100">CDE</code></codes>
3         Other       <codes/>
```

The result I need is (note the `NULL` on the 3rd line)...

```
PROJECTID PROJECTNAME CODESXML
1         This        <codes><code split="45">ABC</code><code split="55">BCD</code></codes>
2         That        <codes><code split="100">CDE</code></codes>
3         Other       NULL
```

Can anybody give me a hint how I can make it return `NULL` when there are no `CODES`?

Comment: +1 for brain fart, oh and your description of the problem.

Comment: you can use case when clause

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd integrate a `CASE WHEN` into that @Viji, can you give an example as an answer?  Or alter the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/62f06/1)?

Comment: Hi, I have included the answer, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT distinct 
    P.[PROJECTID],
    P.[PROJECTNAME],
    case when (p.projectid = c.projectid) then 
    (   SELECT *
        FROM (
                SELECT
                    1 AS TAG,
                    NULL AS PARENT,
                    NULL AS 'codes!1',
                    NULL AS 'code!2!!element',
                    NULL AS 'code!2!split'
                UNION ALL
                SELECT
                    2 AS TAG,
                    1 AS PARENT,
                    NULL,                   
                    C.[CODE],
                    C.[SPLIT]
                FROM [CODES] C
                WHERE C.[PROJECTID] = P.[PROJECTID]
             ) AS [CODEXMLDATA]
        FOR XML EXPLICIT
    ) else null end AS [CODESXML]
FROM [PROJECTS] P
left join [CODES] C on  C.[PROJECTID] = P.[PROJECTID]
```

SQLFiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8788/7/0